# Suspicious links on my wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

Hi guys i really need a help.
My website is in Wordpress platform.

I have this suspicious links added (its like an ADs) on my site everywhere on my page and when you click it will redirect you on the other site.

I have tried to install a anti virus i scanned it already but the website is fine. but the suspicious links are still there

I have tried to disable all the plugins but the suspicious links are still there.

I have tried to remove also the emoji script added on the header (cause this might be the one causing it) but the suspicious links are still there.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: @ste Where should i ask this kind of question?

Comment: @ceejayoz is this really a hacked?

Comment: Maybe on the Wordpress site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Moderate your comment sections and delete all links before you approve it. Or if its publushed then just edit and delete all links. These links can be harmful or not. Most likely used by bots to acquire backlinks from your site for black hat SEO.